# get position of element and create array functions of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having loads of divs which are dynamically created and appended randomly to the body.

```
var cubes    = [], 
    allCubes  = '',
    $fixed    = $('#fixed'),

for(var i = 0; i < 380; i++) {
    var randomleft = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*1500)),
        randomtop = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.floor(Math.random()*1500));
    allCubes += '<div id="cube'+i+'" style="position: absolute; border: 2px #000 solid; left: '+randomleft+'px; top: '+randomtop+'px; width: 15px; height: 15px;"></div>';
    cubes.push($('#cube'+i));
}
```

then I make them all draggable with `jQueryUI` to position them by hand in a shape I would like to.

After that I would like to make `animate()` functions out of every single arraydiv with the position I've dragged before.

```
cubes[0].animate({ top: currentLeftposition, left: currentTopposition}, 500);
cubes[1].animate({ top: currentLeftposition, left: currentTopposition}, 500);
cubes[2].animate({ top: currentLeftposition, left: currentTopposition}, 500);
// and so on until 379
```

But I dont want to type the position of 380 divs by hand. Isn't it possible to create these functions automatically after I dragged every div at the position I want. Means to make a console.log() I could copy and paste with the functions above out of every `cubes[0]` - `cubes[379]`

Hope you get my point.

Comment: Hopefully, you know that `Math.random()` produces a number between 0 and .9, never 1. Therefore 1500 will not be realized. Multiply by 1501 to get 1500.

Comment: @PHPglue yeah I know that, just putted any number in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**something like this?**

```
var cubes = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 380; i++) {
    var rleft = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    var rtop = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500));
    $('#content').append('<div class="cube" style="left: ' + rleft + 'px; top: ' + rtop + 'px;"></div>');
}

//defines cubes
var cube = $('.cube');

//drag  get coord
cube.draggable().on('mouseup', function(i) {
    cube.each(function() {
        var nleft = $(this).offset().left;   
        var ntop = $(this).offset().top;
        console.log('['+i+']'+nleft+','+ntop);
    });
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/YFVXM/

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. Unfortunately this isn't exactly what I intend to do. I don't need to animate the progress between starting position and the new drag position. I'm just using the drag-function to position the divs. There will be no start point, its just that I want to create `cubes[0].animate({ top: currentLeftposition, left: currentTopposition}, 500);` this piece for every div dynamically. Like a console.log() which I can copy and paste into my HTML-Editor. If not I have to read and type the `left, top` properties for 380 divs by hand.

Comment: nice one, exactly what I want. It would be awesome if you could make the log exactly like `cubes[0].animate({ top: currentLeftposition, left: currentTopposition}, 500);`. currentLeftposition/Topposition should be the number which is currently logged!

Comment: as you posted in another thread I'm showing you the problem. http://super-sized.de/neu/ this is the site (guess its better to show you) and it throws me jQuery Objects instead of numbers. But I actually dont get what are you dooing different in the fiddle.

Comment: that would be awesome, but be aware. I guess I will be not able to make something equal for you, if you should post a question haha

Comment: No worries, this seems fun. I've updated this fiddle with exporting and coloring. don't have time to add the importing, but it's not exactly a requirement, would just be cool. see it fullscreen here: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/YFVXM/embedded/result/

Comment: coloring works by switching to coloring mode, clicking the cells you want to color, typing in a `background-color` value like `rgb(0,0,0)` `red` or `#FF0022` and clicking the button to push. there's no reset button so you'll have to toggle back and forth, or unclick all of them to color different cells.

Comment: mate this is stunning! If I could I would accept this as an valid answer as well. Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: importing works now, just had to change the format of the output http://fiddle.jshell.net/filever10/YFVXM/show/light/

Comment: what happens with the importing, or what can I do with it. I actually don't see it.

Comment: move/color a few boxes, generate a report, copy the report, refresh the page, paste the report, and click import.

Answer (score 0):

you could use stop event from API like (inside your for)

```
$('#cube'+i).draggable({
    stop: function(){
            $(this).attr('data-posX', $(this).offset().left);
            $(this).attr('data-posY', $(this).offset().top);
    }
});
```

or store the values as key:value pairs with the #cube -id's or..